# How to wrap `factor level name` in `aggregate` function?

Tags: r

```
> levels(iris$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

I plan to use above names as `xlab` in scripts as below:

```
aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,function(x){
        car::qqPlot(x,distribution="norm",xlab="names(x)")
})
```

[image: 20200507002255276.jpg]

After `qqPlot`,I found `xlab` not resolved.

The general questions is:
How to wrap `factor level name` in `aggregate` function like `aggregate(y~factor,df,function(x){factor level name})`?

Comment: `car::qqPlot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, distribution = "norm")` puts all in the same 2x2 grid plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways, I believe the question asks for the second one. None of th two needs `aggregate`.

**1.** The first way is to use the formula interface directly. It puts all graphs in the same page/plot.

```
car::qqPlot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, distribution = "norm")
```

**2.** The second way splits the data set by the levels of the factor and then `lapply`'s an anonymous function to plot each QQ plot separately.

```
sp <- split(iris, iris$Species)
lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
  sp[[i]]$Species <- droplevels(sp[[i]]$Species)
  car::qqPlot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = sp[[i]], 
              distribution = "norm", xlab = names(sp)[i])
})
rm(sp)    # final clean up
```

Comment: In `aggregate(y~factor,df,function(x){do something to x})`,does `x` has a name?

Comment: Some other similar command like `taaply`,`group_by`,can anyone wrap the level name?

Comment: @kittygirl `x` does not have a name, and you would be interested in the names of the factor, not of `y`, right? Note that in my 2nd code example, you can skip the creation of `sp` and put the `split(.)` inside `seq_along`.

Comment: When put `Sepal.Length ~ Species` into `qqPlot`,ther's no output value.When use `aggregate`,there's some value output.I don't know whether those output valuable?

Comment: @kittygirl What do you mean there's no output? My 2nd solution plots all 3 QQ plots, one for each level of `Species`, with the level as x axis title. What is the code you are running?

Comment: When I run `aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,function(x){
        car::qqPlot(x,distribution="norm",xlab="names(x)")
})`, output is `Species Sepal.Length.1 Sepal.Length.2`
`1     setosa             15             14`
`2 versicolor              1              8`
`3  virginica              7             32`.Is those number valuable?

Comment: @kittygirl Yes they are. But if you want the plots, run my code.